# Regexp соответствующий любому набору символов до первого вхождения подстроки

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Например: строка - "все вот это досюда, а дальше там еще много всего досюда". Подстрока, до которой надо вывести все - "досюда", получить надо "все вот это ".

Comment: Ага. И что вы нам хотите рассказать об этом регулярном выражении? У вас в вопросе отсутствует собственно вопрос.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, всё нормально в вопросе.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Задача решается при помощи следующего регулярного выражения (PCRE):

```
(.*?)досюда
```

В первом совпадении (Match 1) будет искомая подстрока.

Следует обратить внимание на "ленивый" квантификатор (`.*?`). Если бы он был обычным, т.е. "жадным" (`.*`), то результат немного отличался бы от ожидаемого. "Жадный" квантификатор для строки

```
"все вот это досюда, а дальше там еще много всего досюда"
```

выдаст совпадение

```
"все вот это досюда, а дальше там еще много всего "
```

в то время как "ленивый" даст вполне ожидаемый результат:

```
"все вот это "
```

Answer (score 5):

наиболее логичное решение — удаление искомого слова и всех символов после него:

```
s/досюда.*//
```

в строке останется только то, что требуется.

Answer (score 0):

```js
"any text any text any text<stop>other text other text ...".match(/[\s\S]*?(?=<stop>)/)
```